# Every wordpress database query returns NULL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm on a single page inside the loop and every query I try returns NULL. For example:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$users=$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_users" );
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $data );
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here? It does not matter what query I try... Everything returns a NULL

Comment: I'm no wordpress hero, but what is $data? It looks like you are putting some result in `$users` .. maybe you want to look into that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filling $users not $data. Try with

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $users );
```